# Is there something wrong with this Spring WebFlux controller? It gives me a 415 Unsupported Media Type for a response

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm just trying to make a basic HTTP/REST API, for the sake of learning how to use Spring WebFlux.

I have a controller, and I'm trying to make a POST request to create an `Employee`. It's giving me a response saying `415 Unsupported Media Type`. I don't know what that means, or what I'm doing wrong, and I haven't been able to find an answer.

Here's my controller:

```
package io.blainelafreniere.employeesystem;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {
    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    private Mono<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return employeeRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping
    private Flux<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Mono<Employee> create(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

When I make a POST request using Postman, the error I receive is:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-04-21T20:35:52.476+00:00",
    "path": "/employees",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "",
    "requestId": "6cc3d391-5"
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the postman request:

[screenshot of postman POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAi9Y.png)

And here's my Employee entity:

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes in postman you are posting `FORM DATA` when you should be passing `JSON`.